# Can we cover a set with every neighborhood of its points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I have a question about closedness of compact set
in Rudin's PMA. When he wants to prove compact sets are closed. when he constructs $W_q$ from points $q$ in $K$. I can’t understand why ${W_q}$ is an open cover for $K$ and why the union of ${W_q}$ contains $K$. Can someone please clarify can we cover a set with every neighborhood of its points?

Comment: Hi, could you please just specify exactly the definition of $K$ and $W_q$. I assume you want to show that a closed $K$ is compact by finding an open cover, is that right? Any information/properties about the underlying topology?

Comment: no I want to prove complement of K is open so that K is closed.
@NazimJ

Comment: Suppose we have a set $K$ and for every point $q\in K$, we have a neighborhood  $W_q$, so $q\in W_q$. Why is $K\subseteq \bigcup_{q\in K} W_q$? Is this your question?

Comment: (The question is hard to understand as written: you refer to "when he constructs $W_q$ from points $q$ in $K$", so a reader would have to open up a copy of Rudin to find out exactly what $W_q$ is. You should try to provide as much context as possible in your question. In particular, readers should be able to understand the question and all your notation without having to refer to another source.)

Comment: that is my question and you are exactually on point @AlexKruckman

Answer (score 0):

Metric space are [Hausdroff space](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjE4IuMvbT3AhV0zzgGHYM5A-UQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHausdorff_space&usg=AOvVaw3jNZaSIHNO5ma1hoazC3-b). $p$ and $q$ are distinct point in $X$. For concreteness, let $V_q = B(p, \frac{1}{2} d(p,q))$ and $W_q = B(q, \frac{1}{2} d(p,q))$. $V_q$ and $W_q$ are neighborhood of $p$ and $q$, respectively and $V_q \cap W_q =\emptyset$. Note $ \{ W_q | q\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, $\exists \{W_{q_1},…,W_{q_n}\}$ finite subcover of $\{ W_q | q\in K\}$. Define $W= W_{q_1} \cup … \cup W_{q_n}$ and $V= V_{q_1} \cap …\cap V_{q_n}$. Clearly $V$ is a neighbourhood of $p$. We want to show $V\cap W=\emptyset$. Assume towards contradiction, i.e. $\exists z\in V\cap W$. Then $z\in W_{q_i}$, for some $i\in J_n$. So $z\in W_{q_i} \cap V_{q_i} \neq \emptyset$. Thus we reach contradiction. $V\cap K =\emptyset$, since $V\cap W=\emptyset$ and $K\subseteq W$. Thus $V\subseteq X-K$. Hence $p$ is an interior point of $X-K$. Our desired result.

Comment: This is a proof of the result, but it is not an answer to the OP's question. Your line "Note $\{W_q\mid q\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$" is something that can be noted trivially, but it is exactly the point that the OP is stuck on.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I just wanna ask, did you downvote my answer?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks. That was really encouraging. You have some great reflexes. Detect mistakes in secs.

Comment: I think you're being sarcastic, but I do hope that my comment (and downvote) encourages you to try to understand why people are asking the questions they're asking, before writing answers - you'll help a lot more if you meet the question asker at the level of their question. I also commented on the question, encouraging the OP to write better questions with more context. The reason I downvoted your answer but not the OPs question is simply that the OP is a first-time user, while you have >1k reputation. I hope this explanation makes sense to you.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I showed complete proof because of 2 reasons (1) OP question is vague and one can’t “precisely” say this is what OP is asking(at least I wasn’t able to conclusively find OP question) (2) I known where most people will get stuck in that proof, because there was a time(not too long ago) I was stuck in that proof. So I known(vaguely) where OP would find proof difficult. But apparently OP surprised me with his question. I think your downvote was too quick. And I believe one certainly wouldn’t conclude after reading OP question that OP is asking about $A\subseteq B$ meaning.

Comment: @AlexKruckman If that is the case, then OP question is duplicate, because there are thousands post about meaning of $A\subseteq B$ stuff.

Comment: @AlexKruckman To be more specific, OP asked “ I can’t understand why ${W_q}$ is an open cover for $K$ and why the union of ${W_q}$ contains $K$“.  By reading that statement, one would make following conclusions: OP don’t know definition of open cover OR don’t really know what $W_q$ is (explicitly) OR lost in proof. In any situation, my answer is hybrid to all “reasonable” conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a set $K$ and for every point $q\in K$, we have a neighborhood $W_q$, so $q\in W_q$.

You ask: Why is $K\subseteq \bigcup_{q\in K} W_q$?

This is basically trivial, so it might be helpful if I step through it as slowly as possible.

What does $A\subseteq B$ mean? It means that every element of $A$ is an element of $B$.

So let's pick $x\in K$. We want to show $x\in \bigcup_{q\in K} W_q$.

When is $x$ an element of a union of sets? When $x$ is an element of one of the sets in the union.

So we want to show $x$ is in $W_q$ for some $q\in K$.

Well, $x\in W_x$, since $W_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. So we're done.

Comment: now I understand how funny and basic is my question I really appreciate your help. @AlexKruckman

Comment: @NimaBalesini Glad I could help, and welcome to Math Stackexchange! The best way to say "thanks" on this site is by [accepting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/8297) and upvoting answers.